# Does elisp have native sqlite bindings?

Tags: sql, sqlite, emacs, elisp

Are there native SQLite bindings for Elisp? From what I have read, various sql modes in Emacs are more for carrying out sql queries but I think they would work by using the sqlite3 shell command which can be a little slower. I think the fastest way would be to use the SQLite C API from an Emacs C extension and expose all sqlite access through lisp functions.

Has this been done already or is there an easier and better way?

Answer (score 1):

[EDBC](https://github.com/redraiment/edbc) exposes a SQL interface to emacs, although it does it through the command line program rather than the C API.